# Real time document straighener similar to Microsoft Office Lens or CamScanner but for video?

Tags: software-recommendation, streaming

Office lens straightens pictures of flat, boards very, very nicely. Here's an example.

[image]

Let's say I am teaching a class and I want to record what I write on the whiteboard as I explain it. Is there software to apply this straightening effect for a video? Doing it in real time for a live video feed would be even better. The camera would be stationary so the same distortion algorithm would be applied to every frame.

If not, does anyone know of some good libraries/source code of the algorithms used for this type of document straightening? I would be interested in trying to write my own implementation of this for video.

Thank you!

Comment: Something like processing or nodebox might be the go here.